# different maps for different zoom levels in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to create a mixture of maps that will load in depending on zoom level
However, it will only show as one map to the user, and depending on the zoom level, it will load in a different map

I really like open street map data when zoomed out, and skobbler maps when zoomed in, so would like to create this one combined map

I think from what i've read its possible, but all the examples i found refer to detail layers

any examples or pointing in the right direction would be appreaciated

Comment: Aragon posted a detailed answer to a very similar problem at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/different-level-of-detaillayers-on-different-zoom-level-at-openlayers-map - can you have a look and see if that answers your question?